# making image move while key pressed down

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I am trying to make an image move while a key is pressed down. It moves but not fluidly, it wont keep moving as the button is pressed down.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

white=(255,255,255)
black=(0,0,0)

pygame.init()
window=pygame.display.set_mode((640, 360),0,32)
image=pygame.image.load("white.png")
image.set_colorkey(white)

x,y=0,0
movex,movey=0,0

while True:
    window.fill(black)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                movex+=-1
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                movex+=1
            elif event.key==K_UP:
                movey+=-1
            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                movey+=1
    x=movex
    y=movey

    window.blit(image,(x,y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Please fix your indenting

Comment: It has nothing to do with that.

Comment: It probably doesn't, but it would make your code a lot easier for other people to read and copy/paste

Comment: That's much better :)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I think you have to enable some kind of repeat function.
According to [this (your) example](http://sivasantosh.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/keyboard-event-handling-pygame/),

```
pygame.key.set_repeat(50, 50)
```

should do the job.

Explanation [quoted](http://sivasantosh.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/keyboard-event-handling-pygame/):

> What’s with the `set_repeat()` and it’s two arguments? By default the
>   key repeat feature is disabled i.e., the default for when you press
>   and hold a key is nothing. No events will be generated.
>
> The two arguments of set_repeat are delay and interval. When you press
>   and hold a key the first event is generated after delay milliseconds.
>   And the consecutive events are generated after the interval
>   milliseconds.
>
> If this is still confusing then this example might help you. Consider
>   I am holding the up key. This is what the event generation will look
>   like.
>
> [1st up event]…[2nd up event]…[3rd up event]…so on.
>
> The [1st up event] is where the key is pressed and held. And after
>   delay millisecs the [2nd up event] is generated. And then the
>   remaining events are generated every interval millisecs until the key
>   is released.

Comment: this solution clogs up the event queue. Dominic's solution is the one you are looking for

Comment: This is downright bad. Not only is this not reliable and makes the code confusing, you also can no longer regnonize single keystrokes.

Answer (score 9):

You are looking for the `K_DOWN` event, so your image will only move the moment a button is pressed down (or whenever the OS tells you so).

A better idea is to check if certain keys are pressed down each iteration of your main loop, using [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed):

```
...
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if pressed[K_LEFT]:
    movex+=-1
if pressed[K_RIGHT]:
    movex+=1
if pressed[K_UP]:
    movey+=-1
if pressed[K_DOWN]:
    movey+=1

x=movex
y=movey
...
```